# binary sdk for iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk, authentication, binary

i am planning to develop an login sdk for our partners. in their application they use this sdk so they can not get username/password of the users. only sessionId will be return from the sdk and they will use this sessionId to fetch data from server.

this sdk can not be decompiled and can not be tracked. sdk must be a closed-box so the developers can not access user account which is filled in sdk by any user.

it think it must be a binary library. how can i implement such as sdk?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to build a static library with your functions implemented. You can search the web for tutorials how to do that. Some examples are [here](http://mobileorchard.com/code-sharing-via-static-libraries-and-cross-project-references/) and [here](http://www.stormyprods.com/blogger/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html)

Answer (score 1):

Anything can be decompiled.  Any data existing in one process can be read from within that process.   The view hierarchy created by your library can be analyzed and inspected from the application when running, including reading the contents of UITextFields presented by the sdk/library.    There is no way to prevent a motivated application developer who's using your sdk from sniffing the user's data the user enters into objects created and presented by the library.

Comment: i tried with static libary and it works fine. i tried to decompile the .a file with "otool -tV xxx.a" it just prints asm code not class implementation. so it is ok. for me. but you said "...including reading the contents of UITextFields presented by the sdk/library..." how it could be done?

Comment: OK, perhaps "reverse engineered", not "decompiled", sure you won't get source, but it sounded like you wanted it to be impossible for the user of the sdk to figure out what the sdk is doing, and I stand by my answer that you cannot prevent a motivated "cracker" from figuring out exactly what your library does.   Sure, the "casual observer" won't easily discover it, and if that's good enough for you, then fine.